The footer is adding multiple times below different select2 dropdown
I am using select 2 jquery plugin to create multiple multi select dropdowns, At some scenarios the footer is getting appended multiple times under the dropdown menu. For example if you open drodpown 1 and without selecting any option, open dropdown 2 one extra dropdown gets appended and its vice versa. I tried to fix the issue but not able to understand the problem. Can anyone please help.
the working sample code is attached


var temporarySelection = [];
var temporarySelection_level1 = [];
var temporarySelection_level2 = [];
var temporarySelection_level3 = [];
var startDateText = '';
var endDateText = '';
var selectedTextAward = '';
var selectedTextOrg = '';
var selectedTextPillar = '';
var selectedTextLeader = '';
var selectedTextTeam = '';
var selectedDateOpt = '';
let filterRequest = '';
var pillars = [];
let badgifyData = '';
let pageHomeAward_filter = 1;
var shouldClose_myselect = false;
var shouldClose_level1 = false;
var shouldClose_level2 = false;
var shouldClose_level3 = false;
// let jsonData = '';
function formatState(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var selected = ($('#mySelect').val() || []).indexOf(state.id) !== -1;
  var $state = $(
    '<span><input type="checkbox" class="select2-checkbox"' + (selected ? ' checked' : '') + ' /><span class="select2-checkbox-label">' + state.text + '</span></span>'
  );
  return $state;
}

function formatState_Level1(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var selected = ($('#level1').val() || []).indexOf(state.id) !== -1;
  var $state = $(
    '<span><input type="checkbox" class="select2-checkbox"' + (selected ? ' checked' : '') + ' /><span class="select2-checkbox-label">' + state.text + '</span></span>'
  );
  return $state;
}

function formatState_Level2(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var selected = ($('#level2').val() || []).indexOf(state.id) !== -1;
  var $state = $(
    '<span><input type="checkbox" class="select2-checkbox"' + (selected ? ' checked' : '') + ' /><span class="select2-checkbox-label">' + state.text + '</span></span>'
  );
  return $state;
}

function formatState_Level3(state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  var selected = ($('#level3').val() || []).indexOf(state.id) !== -1;
  var $state = $(
    '<span><input type="checkbox" class="select2-checkbox"' + (selected ? ' checked' : '') + ' /><span class="select2-checkbox-label">' + state.text + '</span></span>'
  );
  return $state;
}


function formatSelection(selected) {
  return selected.text;
}

function populateLevel2() {
  var level1Dropdown = document.getElementById("level1");
  var level2Dropdown = document.getElementById("level2");
  var selectedOrganizations = [];

  // Get all selected options in level1 dropdown
  for (var i = 0; i < level1Dropdown.options.length; i++) {
    if (level1Dropdown.options[i].selected) {
      selectedOrganizations.push(level1Dropdown.options[i].text);
    }
  }

  // Initialize an empty array to store unique pillars
  var pillars = [];

  // Extract unique pillars corresponding to the selected organizations
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
    if (selectedOrganizations.includes(jsonData.data[i].Organization)) {
      var pillar = jsonData.data[i].Pillar;
      if (!pillars.includes(pillar)) {
        pillars.push(pillar);
      }
    }
  }

  // Clear the existing options in level2 dropdown
  level2Dropdown.innerHTML = '';

  // Populate the level2 dropdown with options
  for (var j = 0; j < pillars.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = pillars[j];
    level2Dropdown.add(option);
  }
}

function populateLevel3() {
  var level1Dropdown = document.getElementById("level1");
  var level2Dropdown = document.getElementById("level2");
  var level3Dropdown = document.getElementById("level3");
  var selectedOrganizations = [];
  var selectedPillars = [];

  // Get all selected options in level1 dropdown
  for (var i = 0; i < level1Dropdown.options.length; i++) {
    if (level1Dropdown.options[i].selected) {
      selectedOrganizations.push(level1Dropdown.options[i].text);
    }
  }

  // Get all selected options in level2 dropdown
  for (var i = 0; i < level2Dropdown.options.length; i++) {
    if (level2Dropdown.options[i].selected) {
      selectedPillars.push(level2Dropdown.options[i].text);
    }
  }

  // Initialize an empty array to store unique Cost Center Leaders
  var costCenterLeaders = [];

  // Extract unique Cost Center Leaders corresponding to the selected combination of organization and pillar
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
    if (selectedOrganizations.includes(jsonData.data[i].Organization)) {
      if (selectedPillars.length === 0 || selectedPillars.includes(jsonData.data[i].Pillar)) {
        var costCenterLeader = jsonData.data[i]["Cost Center Leader"];
        if (!costCenterLeaders.includes(costCenterLeader)) {
          costCenterLeaders.push(costCenterLeader);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Clear the existing options in level3 dropdown
  level3Dropdown.innerHTML = '';

  // Populate the level3 dropdown with options
  for (var j = 0; j < costCenterLeaders.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = costCenterLeaders[j];
    level3Dropdown.add(option);
  }
}



$(document).ready(function() {


  //get the csv for dropdown
  getDropData();
  const select2Input = document.querySelector('.select2-container .select2-search input[type="search"]');
  if (select2Input) {
    select2Input.style.caretColor = 'transparent'; // Set caret color to transparent
  }
  //myselect ---------------------------------------------------------
  $('#mySelect').select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    templateResult: formatState,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    allowClear: false
  });



  $('#mySelect').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    if (!$('.apply-button').length) {
      $('.select2-dropdown').append(
        '<div class="select2-footer">' +
        '<button class="clear-button">Reset</button>' +
        '<button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>' +
        '<button class="apply-button">Apply</button></div>'
      );
    }

    $('.apply-button').off('click').on('click', function() {
      shouldClose_myselect = true;
      $('#mySelect').select2('close');
      selectedTextAward = $('#mySelect').select2('data')
        .map(option => option.text.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toUpperCase())
        .join(', ');
      console.log("Applying selection: award ", selectedTextAward);

      getFilterDataAward();

    });

    $('.clear-button').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_myselect = true;
      temporarySelection = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#mySelect').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#mySelect').select2('close');
      selectedTextAward = ''
      filterRequest.awardTypeList = null;
      getFilterDataAward();

    });
    $('.cancel-button').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_myselect = true;
      temporarySelection = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#mySelect').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#mySelect').select2('close');
      selectedTextAward = ''
      filterRequest.awardTypeList = null;
    });

    $('.select2-dropdown').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_myselect = false;
    });
  });

  $('#mySelect').on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    if (!shouldClose_myselect) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    shouldClose_myselect = false; // Reset flag
  });

  $('#mySelect').on('select2:select', function() {
    temporarySelection = $('#mySelect').val();
    console.log("tempsel", temporarySelection)
  });

  $('#mySelect').on('select2:unselect', function() {
    temporarySelection = $('#mySelect').val();
    console.log("tempUnsel", temporarySelection)
  });



  //levell1 -------------------------------------------
  $('#level1').select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    templateResult: formatState_Level1,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    allowClear: false
  });
  $('#level1').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    if (!$('.apply-button-level1').length) {
      $('.select2-dropdown').append(
        '<div class="select2-footer">' +
        '<button class="clear-button-level1">Reset</button>' +
        '<button class="cancel-button-level1">Cancel</button>' +
        '<button class="apply-button-level1">Apply</button></div>'
      );
    }

    $('.apply-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level1 = true;
      $('#level1').select2('close');
      temporarySelection_level1 = $('#level1').val() || [];
      selectedTextOrg = $('#level1').select2('data').map(option => option.text).join(', ');
      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';

      console.log("selected-items-myselect", selectedTextOrg)
      $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'block');
      getFilterDataAward();


    });

    $('.clear-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level1 = true;
      temporarySelection_level1 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level1').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level1').select2('close');
      selectedTextOrg = '';
      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';


      filterRequest.organizationList = null;
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.clear-button-level2').trigger('click');
      $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');
      getFilterDataAward();

    });

    $('.cancel-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level1 = true;
      temporarySelection_level1 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level1').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level1').select2('close');
      selectedTextOrg = '';
      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';


      filterRequest.organizationList = null;
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.clear-button-level2').trigger('click');
      $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');
    });

    $('.select2-dropdown').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level1 = false;
    });

  });

  $('#level1').on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    if (!shouldClose_level1) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    shouldClose_level1 = false; // Reset flag
  });

  $('#level1').on('select2:select', function() {
    temporarySelection_level1 = $('#level1').val();
    console.log("tempsel_l1", temporarySelection_level1)
  });

  $('#level1').on('select2:unselect', function() {
    temporarySelection_level1 = $('#level1').val();
    console.log("tempUnsel_l1", temporarySelection_level1)
    if (temporarySelection_level1.length == 0) {
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';
    }
  });


  $('#level1').on('change', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    console.log("selected value", selectedValue)
    populateLevel2(selectedValue);
  });



  ///////level2------------////

  $('#level2').select2({
    placeholder: "Pillar",
    templateResult: formatState_Level2,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    allowClear: false
  });
  $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');

  $('#level2').on('select2:open', function() {
    if (!$('.apply-button-level2').length) {
      $('.select2-dropdown').append(
        '<div class="select2-footer">' +
        '<button class="clear-button-level2">Reset</button>' +
        '<button class="cancel-button-level2">Cancel</button>' +
        '<button class="apply-button-level2">Apply</button></div>'
      );
    }


    $('.apply-button-level2').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level2 = true;
      $('#level2').select2('close');
      $('#level3').select2('close');
      console.log("myyyy level2", $('#level2').val(temporarySelection_level2))
      $('#level2').val(temporarySelection_level2).trigger('change');
      selectedTextPillar = $('#level2').select2('data').map(option => option.text).join(', ');
      selectedTextLeader = '';
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'block');
      console.log("selected-items-myselect", selectedTextPillar)
      getFilterDataAward();

    });

    $('.clear-button-level2').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level2 = true;
      temporarySelection_level2 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level2').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level2').select2('close');
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');
      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';

      getFilterDataAward();
    });

    $('.cancel-button-level2').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#level2').select2('close');
      shouldClose_level2 = true;
      temporarySelection_level2 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level2').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level2').select2('close');
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');

      selectedTextPillar = '';
      selectedTextLeader = '';
    });

    $('.select2-dropdown').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level2 = false;
    });
  });

  $('#level2').on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    if (!shouldClose_level2) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    shouldClose_level2 = false; // Reset flag
  });

  $('#level2').on('select2:select', function() {
    temporarySelection_level2 = $('#level2').val();
    console.log("tempsel_l2", temporarySelection_level2)
  });

  $('#level2').on('select2:unselect', function() {
    temporarySelection_level2 = $('#level2').val();
    console.log("tempUnsel_l2", temporarySelection_level2)
    if (temporarySelection_level2.length == 0) {
      $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
      selectedTextLeader = '';
    }
  });

  $('#level2').on('change', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    console.log("selected value", selectedValue)
    populateLevel3(selectedValue);
  });

  ///level3--------------------

  $('#level3').select2({
    placeholder: "Leader",
    templateResult: formatState_Level3,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    allowClear: false
  });
  $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');

  $('#level3').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    if (!$('.apply-button-level3').length) {
      $('.select2-dropdown').append(
        '<div class="select2-footer">' +
        '<button class="clear-button-level3">Reset</button>' +
        '<button class="cancel-button-level3">Cancel</button>' +
        '<button class="apply-button-level3">Apply</button></div>'
      );
    }

    $('.apply-button-level3').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level3 = true;
      $('#level3').select2('close');
      console.log("myyyy level3", $('#level3').val(temporarySelection_level3))
      $('#level3').val(temporarySelection_level3).trigger('change');
      selectedTextLeader = $('#level3').select2('data').map(option => option.text).join(', ');
      console.log("selected-items-myselect", selectedTextLeader);

      getFilterDataAward();

    });

    $('.clear-button-level3').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level3 = true;
      temporarySelection_level3 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level3').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level3').select2('close');

      selectedTextLeader = '';
      getFilterDataAward();
    });

    $('.cancel-button-level3').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level3 = true;
      $('#level3').select2('close');
      temporarySelection_level3 = [];
      $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('#selected-items').val('');
      $('#level3').val(null).trigger('change');
      $('#level3').select2('close');
      selectedTextLeader = '';
    });

    $('.select2-dropdown').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      shouldClose_level3 = false;
    });
  });

  $('#level3').on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    if (!shouldClose_level3) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    shouldClose_level3 = false; // Reset flag
  });

  $('#level3').on('select2:select', function() {
    temporarySelection_level3 = $('#level3').val();
    console.log("tempsel_l3", temporarySelection_level3)
  });

  $('#level3').on('select2:unselect', function() {
    temporarySelection_level3 = $('#level3').val();
    console.log("tempUnsel_l3", temporarySelection_level3)
  });

});

function getDropData() {
  $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
  $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');

  jsonData = {
    "data": [{
        "Organization": "Finance",
        "Pillar": "Enabling IDC Functions",
        "Cost Center Leader": "Rahul Kakkar"
      },
      {
        "Organization": "Finance",
        "Pillar": "Enabling IDC Functions",
        "Cost Center Leader": "Rohit Sudheer Bhagade"
      },
      {
        "Organization": " Data Ventures",
        "Pillar": "wms Data Venture",
        "Cost Center Leader": "Ramesh Kozhissery"
      },
      {
        "Organization": "WMTUS CORE CUSTOMER CARE",
        "Pillar": "WMTUS - Ops OH",
        "Cost Center Leader": "Balasubrahmanyam Chaturvedula"
      }
    ]
  }
  populateDrop();



}


function populateDrop() {
  console.log("inside dropdata 1", jsonData);
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("level1");
  var organizations = [];

  // Extract unique organization names from the JSON data
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
    var organization = jsonData.data[i].Organization;
    if (!organizations.includes(organization)) {
      organizations.push(organization);
    }
  }

  // Populate the dropdown with options
  for (var j = 0; j < organizations.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = organizations[j];
    dropdown.add(option);
  }

}

function getFilterDataAward(pageNum_filter = pageHomeAward_filter) {
  console.log("filter happening")
}

function clearAll() {
  console.log("clear all")

}
.block-container-component .img-background {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open {
  top: 150px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: text;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 39px;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option .select2-checkbox-label {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-footer {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.apply-button,
.clear-button,
.cancel-button,
.apply-button-level1,
.clear-button-level1,
.cancel-button-level1,
.apply-button-level2,
.clear-button-level2,
.cancel-button-level2,
.apply-button-level3,
.clear-button-level3,
.cancel-button-level3,
#apply-btn-date,
#cancel-btn-date,
#reset-btn-date {
  background-color: #0072dc;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#apply-btn-date {
  display: none;
}

.select2-search--dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none !important;
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option input {
  margin-right: 10px;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#select2-date-range-options-results>.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#select2-date-range-options-results>li {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  color: #999;
  display: none !important;
}

#level1,
#level2 #level3 {
  display: block;
}

#dropdown1,
#dropdown2 {
  margin: 5px;
}

#dropdown2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#date-range-selector {
  margin: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.datepicker {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#level2 {
  display: none;
}

#level3 {
  display: none;
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
  cursor: default;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.hidden-important {
  display: none !important;
}

.flex-important {
  display: flex !important;
}

.drop-header-team {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.drop-header-date {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  position: relative;
  caret-color: transparent !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  position: absolute;
}

#filter-by {
  padding: 10.0px 0.0px 0.0px 5.0px;
  font-size: 15.0px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#clearall-btn {
  margin: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.drop-header-team {
  position: relative;
}

.select2-search__field {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5 !important;
  background: #f6f6f6 !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #454545 !important;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- Include Select2 CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Select2 JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <div id="dropdown1">
    <div class="drop-header-award">Award</div>
    <select id="mySelect" style="width: 300px;" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Bravo</option>
      <option value="2">Impact</option>
      <option value="3">Excellence</option>
      <option value="4">Team Award</option>
      <!-- <option value="5">Service Award</option> -->
      <!-- <option value="6">Tech Fwd</option> -->
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="dropdown2">
    <div class="drop-header-team">Team </div>
    <!-- <span class="tooltip-icon">ℹ️</span> -->
    <select id="level1" style="width: 300px;" multiple>
    </select>

    <select id="level2" style="width: 300px;" multiple>
    </select>

    <select id="level3" style="width: 300px;" multiple>

    </select>
  </div>
  <a id="clearall-btn" onclick="clearAll()">Clear all</a>
</div>




The issue are the selectors inside the select2:open event listener functions. When you open the second select2, your $('.select2-dropdown') selector is finding the dropdown from the first select2 and appending the buttons to that dropdown as well, if you make the selector specific to the select2 instance then it would be fixed.
One way to target the dropdown container for a specific select2 instance is to use this:
var $container = $(e.currentTarget).data('select2').$dropdown;

And this is an example use for the #level1 select2:
//levell1 -------------------------------------------
$('#level1').select2({
  placeholder: "Select",
  templateResult: formatState_Level1,
  templateSelection: formatSelection,
  closeOnSelect: false,
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
  allowClear: false
});
$('#level1').on('select2:open', function(e) {
  var $container = $(e.currentTarget).data('select2').$dropdown;

  if (!$container.find('.apply-button-level1').length) {
    $container.find('.select2-dropdown').append(
      '<div class="select2-footer">' +
      '<button class="clear-button-level1">Reset</button>' +
      '<button class="cancel-button-level1">Cancel</button>' +
      '<button class="apply-button-level1">Apply</button></div>'
    );
  }

  $container.find('.apply-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    shouldClose_level1 = true;
    $('#level1').select2('close');
    temporarySelection_level1 = $('#level1').val() || [];
    selectedTextOrg = $('#level1').select2('data').map(option => option.text).join(', ');
    selectedTextPillar = '';
    selectedTextLeader = '';

    console.log("selected-items-myselect", selectedTextOrg)
    $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'block');
    getFilterDataAward();


  });

  $container.find('.clear-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    shouldClose_level1 = true;
    temporarySelection_level1 = [];
    $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('#selected-items').val('');
    $('#level1').val(null).trigger('change');
    $('#level1').select2('close');
    selectedTextOrg = '';
    selectedTextPillar = '';
    selectedTextLeader = '';


    filterRequest.organizationList = null;
    $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
    $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
    $('.clear-button-level2').trigger('click');
    $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');
    getFilterDataAward();

  });

  $container.find('.cancel-button-level1').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    shouldClose_level1 = true;
    temporarySelection_level1 = [];
    $('.select2-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('#selected-items').val('');
    $('#level1').val(null).trigger('change');
    $('#level1').select2('close');
    selectedTextOrg = '';
    selectedTextPillar = '';
    selectedTextLeader = '';


    filterRequest.organizationList = null;
    $('.select2-container:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
    $('.select2-container:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
    $('.clear-button-level2').trigger('click');
    $('.clear-button-level3').trigger('click');
  });

  $container.find('.select2-dropdown').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    shouldClose_level1 = false;
  });

});

You would probably want to update the listener functions for the other select2 so that they only update their own dropdown.
